# Unable to load class(C:\com\scheduler\jobs) when class has package declaration using URLClassLoader java

Tags: java

I am trying to load  class "SampleTest.class" from folder(C:\com\scheduler\jobs) in my current application, I could able to load class when it doesn't have package declaration.

The problem with  when "SampleTest.class" has package declaration then I couldn't able to load and giving error No class found.

My current application when I am trying to load class :

```
**ReadInterfacesCount.java**

URL url = new URL("file:/C:/com/scheduler/jobs/");
 ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
Class<?> aClass = cl.loadClass("SampleTest");
System.out.println("Interfaces count ==> "+aClass.getInterfaces().length);
```

**SampleTest.class**

```
package com.scheduler.jobs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
```

public class SampleTest implements Serializable{

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

            System.out.println("From Sample Test");
   }
}
```

When I run ReadInterfacesCount it is giving below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SampleTest (wrong name: com/scheduler/jobs/SampleTest)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.test.ReadAllJavaClasses.getListeners(ReadAllJavaClasses.java:119)
at com.test.ReadAllJavaClasses.main(ReadAllJavaClasses.java:101)
```

When I remove package declaration in SampleTest file now I could able to load class.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,
Naresh Kallamadi.

Comment: I've never bothered getting code digested this way, but `Class.forName("SampleTest", ...)` vs `Class.forName("com.scheduler.jobs.SampleTest", ...)` comes to my mind. Quite unrelated to Liferay and Spring (your tags), this is.

Answer (score 2):

As someone upvoted my comment, I'm converting that quick assumption to an answer

When `Class.forName("SampleTest", ...)` fails to instantiate a class named `com.scheduler.jobs.SampleTest`, but succeeds instantiating a class `SampleTest`, you might want to try `Class.forName("com.scheduler.jobs.SampleTest", ...)`

Edit: And as I wrote in the comment, it seems completely weird for me to digest code this way - I've never tried it. The next thing that comes to mind after your comment: When you want to load the class stored in `C:/com/scheduler/jobs/SampleTest.class` as `com.scheduler.jobs.SampleTest`, you might need to give `C:/` as the path to the classloader, because that's the root of where it should search for a class of this package/name.

Coming back to the mentioned weirdness of the code: I don't trust any business level code that explicitly deals with classloading. Classloading is an infrastructure problem, and while you might solve the problem at hand, I believe that you're solving a completely wrong problem - you rather have severe problems with your underlying architecture (which can't be solved in this question)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Olaf Kock, I tried way you suggested no luck.  I changed my code Class.forName() to   cl.loadClass("SampleTest");  still same issue when destination class has package declaration. I could able to load class in both ways when it doesn't have package declaration.